# How to set the properties of custom validation error template in custom user control from parent class

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding, wpf-controls

I have a custom user control with a custom validation error template which is a textblock. What I would like to do is to be able to set the height, width and margin of this textblock from the parent control. I have researched online and on stack overflow but couldn't find a solution. 
I am referring to this line in the usercontrol. I have tried binding and template binding but wasn't successful

```
<TextBlock Name="ErrorBorder"  Width="10" Height="26" Background="Red" Margin="0,0,2,2"> </TextBlock>
```

Is there a way to be able to set the properties of this textblock in user control

custom user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="LearnValidationWthCustomUserCtrl.LabelTextUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearnValidationWthCustomUserCtrl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             x:Name="parent"
             >
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TopLabelText}" FontSize="20" 
                           ></TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding LeftLabelText}" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="{Binding LeftLabelWidth}"
                               ></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding TextBoxText,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                         Width="{Binding TextBoxWidth}"  FontSize="20"  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
                         MaxLength="{Binding MaxLength}" Height="{Binding TextBoxHeight}" Foreground="Green">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate >
                                                <TextBlock Name="ErrorBorder"  Width="10" Height="26" 
                                                               Background="Red" Margin="0,0,2,2" >
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Units}" FontSize="20" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="LearnValidationWthCustomUserCtrl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearnValidationWthCustomUserCtrl"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Grid.Row="1" Height="50" Width="50"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Grid.Row="2" Height="50" Width="50"></TextBox>
        <local:LabelTextUC Grid.Row="3" TextBoxText="{Binding CustomerName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" TextBoxWidth="100"
                           MaxLength="5"   ></local:LabelTextUC>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the TextBlock inside an `<AdornedElementPlaceholder>` will size it to the parent TextBox, so you won't need to specify a width & height:-

```
<AdornedElementPlaceholder>
    <TextBlock Name="ErrorBorder" Background="Red" />
</AdornedElementPlaceholder>
```

Incidentally, you don't need a trigger as WPF will take care of this for you, and only display the error template when the bound property is in error.

Also, why are you using a TextBlock? This will obscure the field whenever it's in an error state, and prevent the user from accessing the TextBox with the mouse. If you are trying to achieve the effect of a red background to indicate an error then I don't think this is possible, as the "adorner layer" is always drawn on top of the control.

It's more common for the error template to draw a red border around the control, e.g.:

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" />
            </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Thanks. The requirement is to have like a red block once the user have inputed the maximum value, not a red border. I could use border instead of textblock like this <Border Name="ErrorBorder" Background="Red" Height="26" Width="10" >
                                                </Border>                                                                              but the parent control still need to be able to set some properties. For example I want the red block to always appear at the end of the textbox.  I feel that I can only achieve this if the parent class can set the left margin

Answer (score 0):

You can expose properties of your `UserControl` with `DependencyProperties`, then bind to those from both inside and outside of the `UserControl`.

`DependencyProperty`:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ErrorBorderHeightProperty
      = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ErrorBorderHeight", typeof(double), typeof(MyUserControl),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((double)20, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault
          | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
    [TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))]
    public double ErrorBorderHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ErrorBorderHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ErrorBorderHeightProperty, value); }
    }
```

Inside your `UserControl`:

```
<TextBlock Name="ErrorBorder"
        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyUserControl}, Path=ErrorBorderHeight}"/>
```

Outside of your `UserControl`:

```
<local:MyUserControl ErrorBorderHeight="10"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. There is an issue with the binding. I get this, when I run the code                                                                                                                                             System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='LearnValidationWthCustomUserCtrl.LabelTextUC', AncestorLevel='1''. 
BindingExpression:Path=ErrorBorderHeight; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='ErrorBorder'); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')